How to share gene expression in a interactive website?
I have a bunch of RNA sequencing data, and I want to make it available on a website upon publication. The basic idea is that when you search by a gene ID, the website will show its expression pattern across different conditions, according to a pre-programmed script. I know how to do it in Rstudio, but I don't have experience in creating websites. I wonder if you have any suggestions on how to do that!

easy, dashboards

Thanks, checking Shiny now

If you can create a shiny application in RStudio, you can deploy the application as a web page. The simplest way is to publish on shinyapps.io, because there's a button right there in RStudio to do that:

The free user accounts on shinyapps.io are quite limited in terms of computation, but may be enough if you're just showing summary data.
It is possible to create a world-accessible shiny server on your own system via Shiny Server, but if you don't have experience setting up web servers it's likely to be more tricky:
https://posit.co/download/shiny-server/
For large data access with scripted computation, you could also try CodeOcean:
https://codeocean.com/

Thanks, for my current use, a free shiny account is enough. Good to know other solutions to more complex tasks!

Could you kindly mark this as "answered" @antbirdINFINITY its a really good answer.
